# MediaPlayer makes artefacts after tracking a song

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When I tracking a song in my app using `player.seekTo(position)` it makes some artefacts like croaking and stuttering short time right after tracking. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems problem solves after changing track position in `onStopTrackingTouch(…)` SeekBar callback instead of `onProgressChanged(…)` changed `fromUser`.